# summarizing all numeric vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame which i need to sum all numeric columns and divide by 4

```
city = c("NY","NY","NY","NY","MI","MI","MI","MI","MI","MI")     
ID = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2")
gender = c("M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F","M","M")
val_1 = c(1,    1,  NA, NA, 2,  NA, NA, 4,  6,  7)
val_2 = c(NA,   4,  4,  7,  9,  10, NA, NA, NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(city, ID, gender, val_1, val_2)
```

to get the output i am writing the code as below

```
df1 =  df %>%
   group_by(city, ID ,gender) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, function(x) sum(x,na.rm = T)/4)
```

Now the problem is if the values are missing then its populating 0's instead of `NA`

Any modification in the above code to get the answer

```
city    ID  gender  val_1   val_2
MI      2   F        1.5    4.75
MI      2   M        3.25   0/NA
NY      1   F         0/NA  2.75
NY     1    M        0.5    1
```

Comment: Add an additional `ifelse` condition in the function, `df %>%
  group_by(city, ID ,gender) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, function(x) 
    ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x,na.rm = T)/4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create an `if/else` to return `NA` `if` `all` the elements are `NA`

```
df %>%
   group_by(city, ID ,gender) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(if(all(is.na(.))) NA else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)/4))
   #or without the if/else
   #summarise_if(is.numeric, funs((NA^all(is.na(.)))*sum(., na.rm = TRUE)/4))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   city, ID [?]
#    city     ID gender val_1 val_2
#  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     MI      2      F  1.50  4.75
#2     MI      2      M  3.25    NA
#3     NY      1      F    NA  2.75
#4     NY      1      M  0.50  1.00
```

Comment: Thanks akrun ... can we do same thing in data.table for time efficiency?

Comment: @sasir The summarise should be almost similar efficiency.  If you want to know how to do this in `data.table` `nm1 <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)];setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(all(is.na(.)) NA else sum(x, na.rm =TRUE)/4), by = .(city, ID, gender), .SDcols = nm1]`

Comment: Thanks akrun for immediate responce